# Box2d - b2EdgeShape & b2ChainShape Depreciated. Now What?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-physics, box2d-iphone

Googling all day could not give me this answer. I have to make an irregular terrain by using `b2EdgeShape` OR `b2ChainShape` as it is explained in the `box2d` manual which is not updated yet because these entities does not exists anymore in the `box2d` library.

What to use in place of these things?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what you want to achieve with these shapes?

Comment: I have to create irregular terrain or you can say irregular ground. All the help I could find on internet regarding this matter uses b2EdgeShape. By reading the box2d manual I had figured out that b2ChainShape will also help me in this regard but both of these items are not found in the latest box2d library.

Comment: chech if it helps.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1

Comment: i've just downloaded the latest box2d version from http://code.google.com/p/box2d/ and these classes are present there. and I don't see anything about deprecation in comments

Comment: Edge shapes were added after v2.1.2. The latest official release is v2.2.1 and currently svn is at v2.3.0. What version are you using? http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas#whichversion

Comment: b2PolygonShape replaced all those specialized shapes.